# Spring Boot Entity how to check value if exist in another table by custom field

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, spring-data

The user can search for products if any product shown in the result exists in the `user_favorites` table so the show flag tells the front-end this product was added for this user by user_id and product_id. with spring boot and spring data.

My Entity :

```
@Id
@Column(name = "catId")
private Integer catId;
@Column(name = "cat_no")
private String catNo;
@Column(name = "cat_sn")
private String catSn;
@Column(name = "doc_ref")
private String docRef;
@Column(name = "user_id")
private Integer userId;
@Column(name = "updated_at")
private String updatedAt;
@Column(name = "created_at")
private String createdAt;
```

I tried that using `@Formula` but nothing happing always returns null. and if it's done by  `@Formula` how can i add parameters to `@Formula`

```
@Formula(value = "SELECT count(*) as checker  FROM fb_user_favorites WHERE cat_id = 34699 AND user_id = '52') ")
@Transient
private String checker;
```

Answer (score 0):

`@Transient` is part of JPA spec. In Hibernate fields marked with this annotation just simply ignored/excluded from any JPA engine/runtime logic.

`@Formula` is part of Hibernate. Fields, marked with it, don't persisted by Hibernate (first argument do not use `@Transient` as redundant), values are calculated by provided SQL when executing query for entity.
So for Hibernate to see this fields, they should not be excluded by `@Transient`

TL;DR remove `@Transient` annotation

Answer (score 0):

Complicated but fast working way.

Adding `isFavorite` field to the entity:

```
@Transient
private boolean isFavorite;
```

Create an entity linking `Product` and `User`:

```
public class ProductFavorite {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne(optional = false, fetch = LAZY)
    private Product product;

    @ManyToOne(optional = false, fetch = LAZY)
    private User user;

}
```

Then create a repository with a method to find the user's favorite products:

```
@Repository
public interface ProductLikeRepository extends JpaRepository<ProductFavorite, Long> {

    @Query("select f.product.id from ProductFavorite f where f.product in ?1 and f.user = ?2")
    Set<Integer> findProductIdsByIdsAndUser(List<Product> products, User user);

}
```

And at the end, write a method that will fill in the isFavorite field:

```
public void fillFavorite(List<Product> products, User user) {
    if (products.isEmpty()) {
        return;
    }
    var likedIds = favoriteRepository.findProductIdsByIdsAndUser(products, user);
    for (Product product : products) {
        product.setFavorite(likedIds.contains(product.getId()));
    }
}
```

You need to call it manually:

```
List<Product> products = productRepository.findAll();
fillFavorite(products, currentUser());
```